# configuring spring cloud config from file or server dynamically

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-cloud-config

I'm developing an application and want to use spring-cloud-config.
My application undergoes massive regression testing and I don't want to start (or to embed in my app) a spring-cloud-config-server for every test. What I want to do is to have a local configuration file that the app will read before spring's bootstrap phase, then according to it it will set the uri of the config server or read it from a local file who's path is in the local conf file.

What is the best approach to do it?

Thanks